# Why var/log/elasticsearch is deleted if I reboot ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and figuring out how to setup ELK stack for logging syslog.

I successfully installed all ELK stacks and it works fine. However, after I installed ELK stack, when I reboot, `var/log/elasticsearch` is somehow deleted so elasticsearch fails to start.

Why `var/log/elasticsearch` is deleted after rebooting system? How should I configure not to delete on rebooting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was due to `/etc/fstab`.

In `/etc/fstab`, `/var/log` was set as tmpf. Thats why `/var/log/elasticsearch/` was being deleted after reboot of system.

So in `/etc/fstab`, it added one more line of `tmpfs /var/log/elasticsearch tmpfs defaults,noatime 0 0`, which enables `/var/log/elasticsearch` not to be deleted after reboot.